# How to replace end of every line that starts with a specific word in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a document that looks something like this:

```
<Objects>
    <Object>
        <Id>1</COLUMN>
        <Type>Type1</COLUMN>
        <Name>Some name</COLUMN>
    </Object>
    <Object>
        <Id>2</COLUMN>
        <Type>Type2</COLUMN>
        <Name>Some name2</COLUMN>
    </Object>
</Objects>
```

How can I replace all the `</COLUMN>` in the end of the lines so they match the type shown in the beginning of the lines using Notepad++? I want the result to be something like this:

```
<Objects>
    <Object>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Type>Type1</Type>
        <Name>Some name</Name>
    </Object>
    <Object>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Type>Type2</Type>
        <Name>Some name2</Name>
    </Object>
</Objects>
```

Comment: I suggest `Find and replace`, using a regex with capturing groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for: `<(\w+)>(.*)</COLUMN>`
Replace with: `<\1>\2</\1>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to match:

```
(<([^>]+)>[^<]+)<\/COLUMN>
```

And replace with the following:

```
\1<\/\2>
```

See [RegEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pE5yY0/1)